# Invite new users into chat

Tags: discussion, support

Sometimes in questions by new users ([this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34700/where-does-blender-go-once-downloaded-cant-find-it-anywhere) for example) the comments go on too long and they should really be moved to chat. But new users don't have the 20 rep needed to write in chat. How can they be invited then?

Comment: Also if you flag a post (a custom message would be helpful, we really do read them), us mods can move the comments in to a chat room.

Answer (score 2):

Moderators can explicitly allow any user access to a certain room, but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way for non-mods to do this.

Try pinging one of the [moderators](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), and if any of us are around we can create a special chat room and a chat profile for the user in question.

If no mods are readily available, then it's trickier. I guess the next best thing you can do is flag the question as "Other" with a message to let us know there is a lengthy comment discussion which can't be continued in chat without a mod.

Comment: I wasn't aware that I could flag to do that..  Users with given amount of Rep should be allowed to invite new users to chat, seems like an arbitrary or not-considered facet of rules.

Comment: @zeffii Flagging as "other" just creates a notification for moderators using whatever message you write and a link to the given post. If you see *any* situation where a moderator could be helpful, don't be shy about flagging it. Regarding allowing an easier way for <20 rep users to chat, that's [one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100291/238438) of [those](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111942/238438) often [requested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82738/238438) features..

Comment: yeah, cool. Those kinds of non-blender but "I don't want to be a big meany about it" threads are very uncommon, and sadly help no-one..  well, maybe the kid.. and maybe that's the help he needs to catapult him to be the next disney . who knows.